# Equivalence for Perfectly Normal

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following equivalence for perfectly normal spaces:

1. $X$ is perfect and normal
2. For every open set $W$ there exists a family $(W_n)_{n \in \omega}$ of open sets such that each $W_n$ is open, $W=\bigcup_n W_n$ and $\overline W_n \subset W$.

I managed to show that 1. implies 2. and that 2. implies that $X$ is perfect, but I need help on showing $X$ is normal.

Edit: $X$ is perfect if and only if every closed subset of $X$ is a $G_\delta$.

Comment: I think that your family must be a cover. Do you mean that the open sets are countable union of closed sets ($F_{\sigma}$)?

Comment: Furthermore, what's perfect in your context? It has no isolated points or it's $G_{\delta}$?

Comment: $G_\delta$, I have just edited the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Suppose $X$ satisfies (2), and let $F , E \subseteq X$ be disjoint open sets.  Then there are families $\{ U_n \}_{n \in \omega}$, $\{ V_n \}_{n \in \omega}$ of open subsets of $X$ such that:

- $F \subseteq X \setminus E = \bigcup_{n \in \omega} U_n$, and $\overline{U_n} \subseteq X \setminus E$ for all $n$;
- $E \subseteq X \setminus F = \bigcup_{n \in \omega} V_n$, and $\overline{V_n} \subseteq X \setminus F$ for all $n$.

Consider the following questions:

1. Given $n \in \omega$, what kind of set is $U_m \setminus \bigcup_{i \leq m} \overline{V_i}$? (and $V_n \setminus \bigcup_{j \leq n} \overline{U_j}$?)
2. Give $n,m \in \omega$, what is $( U_m \setminus \bigcup_{i \leq m} \overline{V_i} ) \cap ( V_n \setminus \bigcup_{j \leq n} \overline{U_j} )$?
3. Given $n \in \omega$, what is $F \cap ( U_n \setminus \bigcup_{i \leq n} \overline{V_i} )$?  What is $E \cap ( V_n \setminus \bigcup_{i \leq n} \overline{U_i} )$?

Answering these questions should lead you to disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $F \subseteq U$ and $E \subseteq V$.

---

For some extra content, this is closely related to the following

> **Fact.** A space $X$ is normal iff for every closed $F \subseteq X$ and every open $U \supseteq F$ there is a family $\{ W_n \}_{n \in \omega}$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $F \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \omega} W_n$ and $\overline{W_n} \subseteq U$ for each $n \in \omega$.

This fact allows you to prove some useful results:

- Every countable regular space is normal.
- Every second-countable regular space is normal.
- Every regular Lindelöf space is normal.

Comment: Thank you very much :) and yes, I had miss typed my question.

Comment: @ViniciusRodrigues: You're welcome!